# Отправка картинки через форму HTML-PHP

Tags: php, html, sendmail

Существует форма, через которую нужно отправить input file.

```
<form class="form-validate" method="post" action="sender.php">
                            <div class="block-fb__wrapper-inputs">
                                <div class="block-fb__input-5"><input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control js-phone"
                                                                      placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" required></div>
                                <div class="block-fb__input-5"><input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"
                                                                      placeholder="Имя (необязательно)"></div>

                            </div>
                            <label class="block-fb__textarea">
                                <textarea name="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Введите пробу, бренд и другие известные вам данные по украшению"></textarea>
                            </label>
                            <div class="block-fb__file">
                                <label for="file" class="br_dropzone">
                                    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" onchange="this.form.fileName.value = this.files[0].name" required>
                                    <span></span>
                                    <input type="text" id="fileName" name="fileName" placeholder="Загрузите или перенесите в поле фото изделия" readonly>
                                </label>

                            </div>
                            <label class="checkbox-label block-fb__checkbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="agree-checkbox">
                                <i></i>
                                Согласен с правилами предоставления информации
                            </label>
                            <div class="block-fb__footer">
                            <span class="block-fb__shield">
                                Гарантируем конфиденциальность и безопасность
                            </span>
                                <button name="ok" class="btn block-fb__btn-submit" type="submit">Получить предложения</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

Файл sender.php

```
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['ok']))
{
    //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
    echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$text = $_POST['text'];
$file =  $_POST['file'];
//hello_world

$email_from = 'akotov1703111@yandex.ru';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Zlg - Сообщение с формы";
$email_body = "Имя: $name.\n". "Номер телефона: $phone \n".
    "Сообщение: $text \n". "Документ: $file \n".
    
$to = "akotov1703@yandex.ru";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
mail($to,"=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($email_subject)."?=",$email_body,$headers);
header('Location: start-page.html');
   
?>
```

Перепробовал всевозможные варианты с _FILES и без него, не могу прикрепить какой либо файл с формы в почту. Подскажите пожалуйста, какой есть самый простой способ вытащить и отправить картинку? Очень буду признателен за помощь, возможно у кого-то есть готовый вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для отправки файлов через форму вам нужно добавить `multipart/form-data`

в итоге у вас должно получится чтото вроде этого

```
<form class="form-validate" method="post" action="sender.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

и потом уже вы можете отловить файл через глобальную переменную `$_FILES`, сохранить его или считать данные из временного хранилища и прикрепить к письму

по этой ссылке можно посмотреть примеры для отправки файла

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12301358/send-attachments-with-php-mail